# Univariate multi-step prediction model for missing value imputation

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns of timestamp and energy usage. The timestamp is taken for every min of the day i.e., a total of 1440 readings for each day. I have few missing values in the data frame.

I want to impute those missing values with deep neural networks, and for this, I have to frame the dataset for developing the neural network. Here's a example of the data:

```
    timestamp           mains_1
0   2013-01-03 00:00:00 155.0
1   2013-01-03 00:01:00 154.0
2   2013-01-03 00:02:00 155.0
3   2013-01-03 00:03:00 NaN
4   2013-01-03 00:04:00 153.0
5   2013-01-03 00:05:00 153.0
6   2013-01-03 00:06:00 153.0
7   2013-01-03 00:07:00 152.0
8   2013-01-03 00:08:00 152.0
9   2013-01-03 00:09:00 152.0
10  2013-01-03 00:10:00 152.0
10  2013-01-03 00:10:00 152.0
11  2013-01-03 00:11:00 NaN
12  2013-01-03 00:12:00 NaN
13  2013-01-03 00:13:00 NaN
14  2013-01-03 00:14:00 149.0
15  2013-01-03 00:15:00 150.0
```

For each NaN, I want to use the past five value as input for my model to predict the NaN
Right now I have this line of code:

```
def prp_data(df, ts, look_back=5, train_fraction=0.80):
"""
Create data for modelling
"""

# Convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=5):
    """
    Create the dataset
    """
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i-look_back:i, 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i, 0])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

# Get dataset
dataset = df[ts].values
dataset = dataset.astype('float32').reshape(-1, 1)

# Split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(dataset) * train_fraction)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]

# Reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = look_back
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)

return trainX, trainY, testX, testY
```

What this does is reframes the data into something like this:

```
    y-5    y-4    y-3    y-2    y-1    y
0   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    155.0
1   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    154.0  
2   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    155.0  
3   NaN    NaN    155.0  154.0  155.0  NaN
4   NaN    155.0  154.0  155.0  NaN    153.0
5   155.0  154.0  155.0  NaN    153.0  153.0
6   154.0  155.0  NaN    153.0  153.0  153.0
7   155.0  NaN    153.0  153.0  153.0  152.0
8   NaN    153.0  153.0  153.0  152.0  152.0
9   153.0  153.0  153.0  152.0  152.0  152.0
10  153.0  153.0  152.0  152.0  152.0  152.0
11  153.0  152.0  152.0  152.0  152.0  NaN
12  152.0  152.0  152.0  152.0  NaN    NaN
13  152.0  152.0  152.0  NaN    NaN    NaN
14  152.0  152.0  NaN    NaN    NaN    149.0
```

I want to train a model for predicting these missing values using only lagged values. As you can see in the data, I have continues missing gaps with different sizes. Now, I think I have to predict the first NaN (for example row 11) and then plug it in the next row and use it for predicting row 12 and so forth. For training and testing the model, I think I need to use rows where y is available as training data and rows where y is NaN as the testing dataset.

Am I doing this correctly? If yes, what should the deep learning model look like? I have experience with Keras and Conv and LSTM layers and I prefer to develop a model that can handle multi-step prediction.

Comment: Observing the values in `mains`, I don't think you'll need a DNN for imputing the missing values. See the section "Time-Series Specific Methods " from [this](https://www.mastersindatascience.org/learning/how-to-deal-with-missing-data/) blog.

Comment: I know about this but it's not what I'm looking for.